# Creating multiple images with imagejpeg loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm building the loop below to generate multiple images using an existing image, and text collect from a user inputed form field. One of the variables is an array that was made by parsing a csv file with names.

The problem I'm running into is that the code only outputs the first image, but not any others. The array has 9 values, but that number can change based off the user's csv.

```
<?php
$school = $_POST["school"];
$educator1 = $_POST["educator1"];
$educator2 = $_POST["educator2"];     
$students = $_FILES["csv"]["tmp_name"];
$csvAsArray = array_map("str_getcsv", file($students));

foreach ($csvAsArray as $value) {

    //Set the Content Type
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    // Create Image From Existing File
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('certificate.jpg');

    // Allocate A Color For The Text
    $black = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 0, 0);
    $grey = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 63, 63, 63);

    // Set Path to Font File
    $font_path = 'GothamRounded-Bold.otf';

    // Print Text On Image
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 90, 0, 90, 920, $black, $font_path, $value[0]);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 50, 0, 850, 1120, $black, $font_path, $school);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 50, 0, 90, 1480, $grey, $font_path, $educator1);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 50, 0, 1050, 1475, $grey, $font_path, $educator2);

    // Send Image to Browser
    // $name = $value[0] .'.jpg';
    imagejpeg($jpg_image);   

    // Clear Memory
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);
}
```

Instead of pushing straight to the browser, I tried to save the image file using the $name variable to create the following, but this did not work either.

```
$name = $value[0] .'.jpg';    
imagejpeg($jpg_image, $name);
```

Comment: You cannot display multiple images like this, because you're sending the freshly generated image to the browser directly. Instead, you'll need to save all those images to one file each and make them accessible in the browser over a link to display them.

Comment: That is what I suspected, but I tried to use the following code and it does not work.

$name = $value[0] .'.jpg';    
imagejpeg($jpg_image, $name);

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return several images at once in this way. Here is the options I can suggest you:

1. Pack them all into zip or something and then return as single file
2. Glue them up and return as single picture
3. Save them on server in a public directory, and provide direct links in response to end-user

Comment: I like option #3, but is there a reason why I can not do that using the imagejpeg function? I'm using this code, but it does not seem to work. imagejpeg($jpg_image, $name);

Comment: Well, let's figure out what's wrong. Do you get any error? What is your tmp files dir? You can check it using `sys_get_temp_dir()` function. See docs here http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php. Or directly in your `php.ini` configuration file(should be something like `upload_tmp_dir`, just search by 'tmp').

Comment: I got no php error on the browser page. Just a blank page with a question mark in the middle which I think means it thinks an image is suppose to go there. The php.ini file says the temp files dir is /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/ since I'm running this locally.

Comment: Have you checked this tmp folder for created images? Also, please check folder containing your executable php file. Another thing, is that you must remove `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` in this case. it's only required, when the body of your response contains image data.

Comment: That's why you have this questinon mark, I guess, because of header.

Comment: Thank you! I figured half of it and the other half you got. Basically the local folder was set to read only. I had to set it to read and write to get the images to save. To remove the ? I had to remove the header like you mentioned. I'm a beginner, so thanks for helping.

Comment: You are wellcome! I had thoughts about directory permissions but skipped it because I almost never experienced it on Windows. I'm glad that you found the root cause :)